# I keep getting the same error code ORA-00933

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not quite sure where this is going haywire. I'll get the code "00907 missing right parenthesis" so, I add the parenthesis and then I'll get the "00933 error"

```
SELECT  RENTER.RENTER_ID,
    RENTER_LNAME,
    Round((Count(DEP_ID)+1)/APART_BED) AS "PEOPLE / BEDROOM"
FROM RENTER JOIN DEPENDENT ON RENTER.RENTER_ID = DEPENDENT.RENTER_ID
        JOIN LEASE ON LEASE.RENTER_ID = RENTER.RENTER_ID
        JOIN APARTMENT ON APARTMENT.APART_NUM = LEASE.APART_NUM
WHERE RENTER_ID = ((LEASE_END) = '30-JUN-18')
ORDER BY RENTER_ID;
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  That is only part of your problem.  You might also want to provide sample data, desired results, and a description of what you want to do -- in another question.

Comment: Here is the question I'm trying to answer. Write a query to display the renter ID, last name, and the number of people per bedroom of the apartment. The people per bedroom is calculated as the renter plus the number of dependents associated with the renter, divided by the number of bedrooms in the apartment. Remember, not all renters will have dependents, but the renter is still counted as a person. Limit the results to only leases for apartments that end on June 30, 2018. Sort the results by the number of people per bedroom in descending order, then by renter ID in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this one:

put alias or name of table before column name from which table you want to use column.

Here i assume that you want `RENTER_ID` from `RENTER` table.

```
SELECT RENTER.RENTER_ID,
  RENTER_LNAME,
  ROUND((COUNT(DEP_ID)+1)/APART_BED) AS "PEOPLE / BEDROOM"
FROM RENTER
    JOIN DEPENDENT
        ON RENTER.RENTER_ID = DEPENDENT.RENTER_ID
    JOIN LEASE
        ON LEASE.RENTER_ID = RENTER.RENTER_ID
    JOIN APARTMENT
        ON APARTMENT.APART_NUM = LEASE.APART_NUM
    WHERE RENTER.RENTER_ID        = LEASE_END
      AND RENTER.RENTER_ID          = '30-JUN-18'
    ORDER BY RENTER_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in the WHERE CLAUSE, you can't write:

```
 WHERE RENTER_ID = ((LEASE_END) = '30-JUN-18')
```

You have to write two separate conditions, for example:

```
WHERE RENTER.RENTER_ID = LEASE.RENTER_ID
AND LEASE.LEASE_END = '30-JUN-18'
```

Example Query:

```
SELECT RENTER.RENTER_ID,
       RENTER_LNAME,
       Round((Count(DEP_ID) + 1) / APART_BED) AS "PEOPLE / BEDROOM"
  FROM RENTER
  JOIN DEPENDENT
    ON RENTER.RENTER_ID = DEPENDENT.RENTER_ID
  JOIN LEASE
    ON LEASE.RENTER_ID = RENTER.RENTER_ID
  JOIN APARTMENT
    ON APARTMENT.APART_NUM = LEASE.APART_NUM
 WHERE RENTER.RENTER_ID = DEPENDENT.RENTER_ID
 AND LEASE.LEASE_END = '30-JUN-18'
 ORDER BY RENTER_ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  RENTER.RENTER_ID,
    RENTER_LNAME,
    Round((Count(DEP_ID)+1)/APART_BED) AS "PEOPLE / BEDROOM"
FROM RENTER JOIN DEPENDENT ON RENTER.RENTER_ID = DEPENDENT.RENTER_ID
        JOIN LEASE ON LEASE.RENTER_ID = RENTER.RENTER_ID
        JOIN APARTMENT ON APARTMENT.APART_NUM = LEASE.APART_NUM
WHERE RENTER_ID = LEASE_END AND RENTER_ID = '30-JUN-18'
ORDER BY RENTER_ID;
```

Comment: When I changed my WHERE line to the one above I'll get error 00918 with the cursor in front of the second RENTER_ID in the WHERE line.

Comment: You need to get rid of the parenthesis in the `WHERE` clause.